# How to extract all date formats only via regex expressions

Tags: python, regex, jupyter, python-tesseract

```
r'(?:\d{1,2}[-/th|st|nd|rd\s]*)?(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)?[a-z\s,.]*(?:\d{1,2}[-/th|st|nd|rd)\s,]*)+(?:\d{2,4})+')
```

This is my regex expression. The images I have are like,  Due Date  23 September 2022  and
Dated   14 Sep 2022  etc.

I want to extract only dates out of it. The above is the regex expression I used but the output in jupyter notebook is like ated 14 Sep 2022.

The 'ated' of 'dated' is coming but I want only date format like 14 Sep 2022.  Is there any alternation that I need to do? Kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your pattern does not match `ated` See https://regex101.com/r/R3KjTe/1

Comment: Thanks but there is date format as Due Date  19/06/2016 So, it is displaying the result as ate  19/06/2016. Shall I know why the output is coming like this.

Comment: Try making the pattern case insensitive `(?i)\b(?:\d{1,2}[-/th|st|nd|rd\s]*)?(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)?[a-z\s,.]*(?:\d{1,2}[-/th|st|nd|rd)\s,]*)+(?:\d{2,4})+` See https://regex101.com/r/wxQJTd/1

Answer (score 0):

The regex you have given can't match the word "Dated". The "ated" being returned/printed means there is something being in the source code itself since the regex pattern starts with `(?:\d{1,2}[-/th|st|nd|rd\s]*)?` and will only look for 1 or 2 digit number followed by the matches in the character class.

[Here's the match result I got on regex101 website.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ee7ya.png)

You may execute it yourself here: https://regex101.com/r/XnOhsK/2

Edit: That "ated" is caught by `\s` in `(?:\d{1,2}[-/th|st|nd|rd)\s,]*` group.

Comment: Thanks but there is date format as Due Date  19/06/2016 So, it is displaying the result as ate  19/06/2016. Shall I know why the output is coming like this.

Comment: @TanujKanda that is because of the third group `[a-z\s,.]*` in regex. The `\s` matches any string.